# C String is correct in one function and dumps garbage in the other

Tags: c, string

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abc(char *text);

int main(void)
{
    char text[20];
    abc(text);
    printf("text in main : %s\n",text);
    return 0;
}

void abc(char *text)
{
    text = "abc";
    printf("text in abc function : %s\n",text);
}
```

And this is output.

```
text in abc function : abc
text in main : ฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬฬ๑ป ๚
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the text variable in the main function and in the `abc` function is not the same?
2. I try to change to use `scanf` in the `abc` function and it works! there are the same. Why?
3. How to modify the code to make it work. I means from question1 that make main function and in abc function are the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call the function:

```
 abc(text);
```

a copy of the pointer `text` is made, and this pointer is the one used in the function `abc()`. So that when you say:

```
text = "abc";
```

you are changing the copy, not the one back in `main`.

Also, you cannot in general assign strings in C - you have to use library functions like `strcpy()` instead. To make your code work, you need to change:

```
 text = "abc";
```

to:

```
 strcpy( text, "abc" );
```

Comment: A really easy mistake for newbies to make with pointers, they can take a little while to wrap your head around

Comment: If I have an address of text in main function, can I modify in abc function (Pass by reference) ?

Comment: @Atom The code I posted will modify the buffer in main - have you tried it?

Answer (score -3):

You can't just `printf("text in main : %s\n",text);` it has no meaning in C, you either can use a function like `strcpy()` that takes each char and **organize them to be a *String*** ! or a regular for loop and run it all over the array and print organs without space.

```
int i;
for (i=0 ; i<strlength(text);i++)
{
    printf ("%d",text[i]);
}
```

Comment: I believe it's strlen() not strlength for C (strlength is C++ I believe).  The %s format identifier most definitely will work with his example, and %d will show the ASCII representation of text[i], you want %c there.